# Angular Material - drag and drop set new position

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, drag-and-drop

I need help with Angular material drag-drop

the idea is that I can move the block of black color on the screen along the Y axis, for this I use Angular Material drag and drop, for this I have 3 methods onDragMoved, onDragStart, onDragEnd. When I release the mouse , I will add 100px to the height , and when I want to start moving the block for the second time , it should start moving from the point where it stopped last time , but this does not happen , some kind of twitching occurs

video with problem - https://dropmefiles.com/0XFU6

```
onDragMoved(event: CdkDragMove) {
    console.log('движемся')
    console.log(event)
    console.log('neeeew coord', this.qwwqwqw)


    // if(this.qwwqwqw != null && event != null) {
      // event.distance.y = this.qwwqwqw
      // event.pointerPosition.y = this.qwwqwqw
      // this.qwwqwqw = null;
    // }
    
  }

  onDragStart(event: CdkDragMove) {
    console.log('Кнопка мыши зажата');
    console.log(event.distance)
  }

  onDragEnd(event: CdkDragMove) {
    console.log('Кнопка мыши отпущена');
    console.log(event)

    const y = event.distance.y + 100; // получаем координату Y курсора мыши при отпускании элемента и добавляем 100
    const element = event.source.element.nativeElement;
    element.style.transform = `translate3d(0, ${y}px, 0)`; // устанавливаем новую позицию элемента с помощью CSS-трансформации
    element.style.height = this.originalHeight + 'px'; // восстанавливаем исходную высоту блока

    event.distance.y = y;
    this.qwwqwqw = y;
  }
```

```
<div class="example-box" cdkDragLockAxis="y" cdkDrag (cdkDragMoved)="onDragMoved($event)"  (cdkDragStarted)="onDragStart($event)" (cdkDragEnded)="onDragEnd($event)">
  Координаты: {{ posX }}, {{ posY }}
</div>
```

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgbnB.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmWP2.png)

I tried debugging  , I pass the new coordinates to the onDragMoved method , but on the 2nd event they are updated to some random ones

Answer (score 0):

Use [cdkDragFreeDragPosition] property

**HTML:**

```
<div class="example-box" cdkDragLockAxis="y" cdkDrag [cdkDragFreeDragPosition]="dragPosition" (cdkDragEnded)="onDragEnd($event)">
    Координаты: {{ posX }}, {{ posY }}
</div>
```

**TS:**

```
dragPosition = { x: 0, y: 0 };

onDragEnd(event: CdkDragMove) {
    this.dragPosition = { x: event.distance.x, y: event.distance.y + 100 }
}
```